In the rims of hell, A river flows
In the rims of hell,
A river flows
Upon it, a growl forms
Two brothers, fighting for lost cause
Loved one another
Could not look in the eye
For he was on fire
He screamed liar
to his lover
Before he choked her
For a vain desire
The warrior groweled
For he had been burned
The man who was once great
Lost, in his hate
Can you find this lost warrior?

It's just an statement that it is easy, this is my first puzzle/riddle so I wanted to make an easy riddle for my first time.

I think the lost warrior may be

 ANAKIN SKYWALKER

As found in

 the script to Star Wars Episode III (interestingly, the same battle found in another recent puzzle).

Reasoning:
In the rims of hell,
A river flows

 OBI-WAN is trapped. He looks over the balcony and into a river of lava.

Upon it, a growl forms

 SNAPPING AND METAL GROANS are heard as the main part of the collector starts to break away and move toward the lava fall. (or any of the other battle sounds)

Two brothers, fighting for lost cause
Loved one another

 OBI-WAN: You were my brother, Anakin. I loved you

Could not look in the eye
For he was on fire

 OBI-WAN looks in horror as ANAKIN becomes engulfed in flames. OBI-WAN can't watch him as he struggles to climb the embankment, covered in flames.

He screamed liar
to his lover

 PADME: Because of what you've done . . . what you plan to do. Stop, stop now. Come back! I love you.

 ANAKIN: (seeing Obi-Wan) Liar!

Before he choked her
For a vain desire

 ANAKIN reaches out, and PADME grabs her throat as she starts to choke.

The warrior groweled
For he had been burned
The man who was once great
Lost, in his hate

 Suddenly ANAKIN bursts into flames and starts SCREAMING.
 ...ANAKIN drops, smoldering, near the top of the lava pit.
 - The growl also may refer to his anguish at being told that Padme is dead:
DARTH SIDIOUS: I'm afraid she died. ... it seems in your anger, you killed her.
A LOW GROAN emanates from Vader's mask.


 So Anakin is the warrior, lost in his hatred of Obi-Wan.


Another strange coincidence, I actually watched this yesterday with my daughter (it was the next one she needed to watch, for completeness - which is probably the only reason ever to watch this film...). I can confirm that your answer doesn't just fit the script but also the final work. I can also confirm that it is soooooo bad (the final work, not your answer!)...

Yuppp! I think you can see how much of a fan I am:)
